# Clear float among contiguous float entites in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
    div {
    background:red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
    }
    .clear {
        clear:left;
    }
```

Take 1,2,3,4 as div layout position in sequence.

The standards-compliant browser layout is:

1

2 3 4

while IE6 weirdly render as:

1 3 4

2

In IE6 the float entity static 'baseline' won't change even the previous element have set clear.

How to fix this bug??

Comment: Are you required to support IE6? All web shops I know of have explicitly dropped support for it.

Comment: I agree with @Sam -- if you have a choice, drop IE6 support. If you don't have a choice, tell them it'll double the development cost to support it, and reduce functionality. IE6 has several severe rendering bugs which you simply cannot work around without breaking the site in other browsers. You'll need lots of conditional comments if you want to support IE6 and other browsers at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

IE 6 & **7** were affected by this.

Use the tried and true `<br>` float clearer

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/ce4UK/

**HTML:**

```
<div></div>
<br class="clear" />
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    background:red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}
.clear {
    clear:left;
}
```

Comment: yep,it can add structure tag to separate the layout.But I wonder whether there exist tricks or hack to work around without additional tags.Is it no other better way so far??

Comment: I've updated the post, really the `<br>` float clear method has been around for a while.  It's tried and true.  I really don't think there's getting around a structure tag.